# Repeat-While Loop with Dictionary Swift

Tags: swift

> I am trying to get this loop to run correctly but it will not continue. If the user doesn't enter a value that matches the dictionary, I need it to round down to the closest match and then print the value.

```
let dict = FitnessScore.powerThrow
var input = 19.30
var correctInput = false

func checkKey(score: Double) -> Bool {
    for (key, _) in dict {
        if key == input {
            correctInput = true
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func getFinnalInput() -> Double {
    repeat {
        input -= 0.1
        checkKey(score: input)
        print("this is the new input value: \(input)")
        print("thie is the new condition: \(checkKey(score: input))")
        return input
        
    } while correctInput == true
}
print("your input score rounded down to \(getFinnalInput())")

struct FitnessScore {
    static let powerThrow = [
        12.50: 100,
        12.40: 99,
        12.20: 98,
        12.10: 97,
        11.90: 96,
        11.80: 95,
        11.60: 94,
        11.50: 93,
        11.30: 92,
        11.20: 91,
        11.00: 90,
        10.90: 89,
        10.70: 88,
        10.60: 87,
        10.40: 86,
        10.30: 85,
        10.10: 84,
        10.00: 83,
        9.80: 82 ]
}
```

Comment: Use the input value to find the smallest difference from each.

Comment: Seems like you just need `FitnessScore.powerThrow.keys.sorted().last { $0 <= input }`?

Comment: What is the expected result for input < 9.8? Apart from that I think the solution above from @Jessy is the way to go

Comment: Joakim- that's why .first or .last isn't working or im just not understanding. Im trying not to get a picker for each value so the user can enter a wide range of integers. if the user gets 9.9 they don't get points for 10.00. it rounds to 9.8.

Comment: Yes and that works with the above solution since it selects the closest value below the entered. What I asked about is what the points the user should get for a lower value like 9.5?

Answer (score -2):

```
let userEntered = "12.9"
var input = Float(userEntered) ?? 0.0

func checkKey(score: Float) -> Bool {
    let dict = FitnessScore.powerThrow
    for (key, _) in dict {
        if key == score {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func getFinnalInput() -> Float {
    if checkKey(score: input) {
        return input
    } else {
        repeat {
            input -= 0.1
            input = roundf(input * 100) / 100
            print("this is the new input value: \(input)")
            print("thie is the new condition: \(checkKey(score: input))")
            checkKey(score: input)
        } while checkKey(score: input) == false
        return input
    }
}
print("your input score rounded down to \(getFinnalInput())")
```

Comment: Not only inefficient but if the starting value for input is lower than the smallest key you have an infinite  loop or if input has a third digit (11.201), this will also loop forever and floating point precision might also become an issue.